# Vegan sport player?

Tags: trivia, international-sports

In this era where, in my opinion, power is necessary so I have a question about alimentary habits for most important sport players.

How many and who famous international sport (tennis/football/volleyball/basketball/winter sports/athletics) player is declared as vegan?

Comment: Who declares this?

Comment: I do not know if anyone declares this. It is the object of the question

Comment: The athlete declares him/herself as vegan?

Comment: I learned a new word today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Numerous professional sports players have declared as vegan. There's even a website devoted to their declarations.

http://www.greatveganathletes.com/

There aren't very many athletes featured there, but there are some other lists of vegan or *near* vegan professional sports participants that are available with some searching on the web. For instance, the recently retired future NFL hall of famer Tony Gonzalez is vegetarian and nearly vegan.